# Updating the minimum count for ecs using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ecs

With AWS boto3 , we are able to use the update service to set desired count to 0. Is there a way to update the minimum count also. Any suggestions

Answer (score 3):

Taking the reference from this [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/933583/how-to-update-the-minimum-maximum-number-of-running-tasks-in-ecs), you'll have to do it in 2 steps, using [application auto-scaling boto3 client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/application-autoscaling.html):

1. Create your ECS service as Application auto-scaling target with `register_scalable_target()` with for example `MinCapacity=3` and `MaxCapacity=100`. This call will return the scalable target ARN.
2. Every evening call `register_scalable_target()` again with MinCapacity=0 and every business day morning again with `MinCapacity=3`.

See the [register_scalable_target()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/application-autoscaling.html#ApplicationAutoScaling.Client.register_scalable_target) documentation where it explicitly says:

> After you have registered a scalable target, you can use this
> operation to update the minimum and maximum values for its scalable
> dimension.

Your auto-scaling policy will then set DesiredCapacity within the Min/MaxCapacity boundaries where the MinCapacity will change from 0 to 3 during business hours and back to 0 after hours.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum count would be part of an Auto Scaling configuration. You would update that through the `ApplicationAutoScaling` client's `put_scaling_policy()` method, documented [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/application-autoscaling.html#ApplicationAutoScaling.Client.put_scaling_policy).